# opencv framework not found in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, swift, opencv

I'm trying to add opencv framework into built project(https://github.com/amolaks76/iOS-Camera-and-OpenCV) I found from Github. I'm just trying to run the app on my iPhone to see how opencv works with Swift. 
I added `opencv.framework` which I found from opencv website. Even if I add the framework, it still complains like below image.
[image]

one thing I found is that opencv.framework has different image than apple's framework like below:
[image]

I've seen other stackoverflow questions about this matter and people suggested to make sure `Always Search User Paths` is `Yes`. I'm updating my search path setting below:
[image]

can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following

```
#import "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

and in build settings -> compile as -> objective c++

Answer (score 0):

you need to download ovencv frame work from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv
add it to your project